# How to "wash out" colors with CSS filters?

Tags: css

I am trying to use CSS filters to create a "disabled" look for components I am working on. I am trying to make it so that everything is "washed out" a bit. I can create this effect by using `opacity(0.75)` for components which are on white background: then black becomes gray and all strong colors become a bit more white. But the issue is if the component is not on white background, then opacity does not work as I would like. So how could I use CSS filters to create this "wash out" look? Like to multiply with white color a bit all colors.

I tried `contrast` but it looks like everything goes to gray, not white (so black stays black much longer than with opacity, while other colors are already washed out).

Comment: add a transparent white overlay on its top?

Comment: A JS approach here, just as a FYI in case it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47022484/1225328

Comment: Overlay prevents user to interact with content, like copying data they might want to copy out of the form.

Comment: you add pointer-events: none to the overlay

Comment: @TemaniAfif: I forgot about that. A good point. But the overlay still has a problem that it is easy only if the component is rectangular. If you have rounded edges, then you have to match that on the overlay as well, so it becomes complicated to keep things in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of Contrast and Brightness filters might give you what you need:

```
filter: contrast(30%) brightness(150%);
```

Comment: Nice. The `contrast(30%) brightness(150%)` does not make the background really white, if you start with white, but it becomes a bit gray, but it is a good direction. Still, it does not look exactly the same, but it is a good approximation.